# Solve the equation on the interval $0 \le \theta\le2\pi $

Tags: trigonometry

I have this Final Math Exam Review, for Math Analysis/Trig = Pre-calculus. So I stumbled upon my review and this section arose where it told me to

> Solve the equation on the interval $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi $

Honestly, I completely forgot this topic and have no idea how to do this. The questions of that topic is (the review is multiple choice)

> > $2\cos^2\theta -1 = 0$
> >
> > $\sec(\frac{3\theta}{2}) = -\sqrt2$
> >
> > $\cos(2\theta) = \frac{\sqrt3}{2}$
> >
> > $\cos(2\theta - \frac{\pi}{2}) = \frac{\sqrt2}{2}$

If you guys can kindly solve one of them for me, I am pretty sure I can solve the rest, or tell me the logic necessary to solve these types of questions.

Comment: Ok... first time I received a downvote for asking review questions.

Comment: Do you know some trig identities? Did you draw a unit circle with some angles?

Comment: No i forgot what i learned for math....... I was lazy sorry @B.Pasternak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's examine the first problem.
\begin{align*}
2\cos^2\theta - 1 & = 0\\
2\cos^2\theta & = 1\\
\cos^2\theta & = \frac{1}{2}\\
\cos\theta & = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\cos\theta & = \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}
\end{align*}
Treating the two cases separately yields
\begin{align*}
\cos\theta & = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} & \cos\theta & = -\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\\
\cos\theta & = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) & \cos\theta & = \cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)
\end{align*}
By symmetry, $\cos\theta = \cos(-\theta)$.

[image: symmetry_diagram_for_sine_and_cosine]

Since coterminal angles have the same cosine, we conclude that $\cos\theta = \cos\varphi$ if 
$$\varphi = \pm\theta + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Hence, 
$$\cos\theta = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \implies \theta = \pm \frac{\pi}{4} + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
and 
$$\cos\theta = \cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right) \implies \theta = \pm \frac{3\pi}{4} + 2n\pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
The requirement that $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ determines the permissible values of $n$.
\begin{align*}
\theta & = \frac{\pi}{4} + 2n\pi \in [0, 2\pi] \implies n = 0 \implies \theta = \frac{\pi}{4}\\
\theta & = -\frac{\pi}{4} + 2n\pi \in [0, 2\pi] \implies n = 1 \implies \theta = \frac{7\pi}{4}\\
\theta & = \frac{3\pi}{4} + 2n\pi \in [0, 2\pi] \implies n = 0 \implies \theta = \frac{3\pi}{4}\\
\theta & = -\frac{3\pi}{4} + 2n\pi \in [0, 2\pi] \implies n = 1 \implies \theta = \frac{5\pi}{4}
\end{align*} 
Substituting these values into the original equation demonstrates that they are valid solutions.  For instance,
\begin{align*}
2\cos^2\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) - 1 & = 2\left[\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right]^2 - 1\\
& = 2\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)^2 - 1\\
& = 2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2 - 1\\
& = 2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) - 1\\
& = 1 - 1\\
& = 0
\end{align*}
Hence, the solution set is $$S = \left\{\frac{\pi}{4}, \frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{5\pi}{4}, \frac{7\pi}{4}\right\}$$

Comment: The millionth time i said this but : Thanks a lot Sir!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well for the first equation you can isolate $\theta$:

$2\left(cos(\theta)^2\right)=1$

$\left(cos(\theta)\right)^2=\frac12$

$\left(cos(\theta)\right)=\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Can you solve the rest of this question?

The rest of them are quite similar. The only thing that might be different is using a trigonometric identity to bring it to a form thats easier to solve

Edit: Here is a unit circle. Find all the angles where 
$cos\theta=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ in your interval. It's crude, and you should probably know how to solve this off by heart. Use this as a starting point.

[image: Image circle]

Another hint:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$

Comment: Kk sec.. let me finish this code thing, and ill come back at you. dont leave m!

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the "well known" special values of the trig functions $\cos$ and $\sin$, as well as their global symmetries. I'll do problem 3) here:

We know that within a full period $[-\pi,\pi]$ one has $\cos x={\sqrt{3}\over2}$ iff $x=\pm{\pi\over6}$. Therefore $2\theta=\pm{\pi\over6}$ mod $2\pi$. This implies $\theta=\pm{\pi\over12}$ mod $2\pi$, or else $\theta=\pm{\pi\over12}+\pi$ mod $2\pi$. It follows that we obtain four solutions per period. Their representants in the interval $[0,2\pi]$ are $\bigl\{{\pi\over12}, {5\pi\over12}, {7\pi\over12}, {11\pi\over12}\bigr\}$.